# FIFO Data Matching by Each

Tags: ms-access

Way out of my depth here - hoping to get help.

I use Access to arrange 3 sets of data. Promise Date, Delivery Date and Production Date to look for On Time Delivery, On Time Production, Etc.

There are no links that pair these 3 tables. We might build 5 pieces and ship 3 to one and 2 to another, so I can't do a lookup based on quantity movement.

Instead, I break each table into "Eaches" by date and match them in a FIFO fashion.

Thus the first unit produced probably belongs to the first unit shipped, etc.

This requires a tremendous amount of manual manipulation, primarily sorting by date and putting back into Access.

Is there a way to take a table, break it into eaches, and sort & count that table by date?

It would take this:

Prod / Date / Qty
X / Jan-10 / 2
Y / Feb-10 / 2
Z / Mar-10 / 2

And turn it into this:

Prod / Date / Qty / Order
X / Jan-10 / 1 / 1
X / Jan-10 / 1 / 2
Y / Feb-10 / 1 / 1
Y / Feb-10 / 1 / 2
Z / Mar-10 / 1 / 1
Z / Mar-10 / 1 / 2

I could link the tables together from there - but can't figure out how to do it outside of Excel sorting and formulas that look at rows above.

Comment: Is this an Excel problem, an Access problem, or are you trying to do it in some programming language?

Comment: Sorry - it looks like it formatted the question strangely. Supposed to have char return after each qty.

Comment: I'd like to be able to do all of this in Access without VBA - but I could do some basic VBA if it worked.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, so if this doesn't relate to VBA it's probably off-topic.